# How to add a class dynamically to a href?

Tags: jquery

I have been provided with this css

```
<a href="#" class="tpActive">Butter Extra - Rs. 25/-</a>
```

I have been trying this way

```
 $(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function (e) {

 //  if(whetherchecked)
   // {
var name = $(this).attr("name");

var topping='<div class="Topping-details"><section><a href="#">'+name+'</a></section></div>';
//$( "a" ).addClass( "tpActive" );
//$(this).addClass(background-color: Green!important);
$( this ).addClass( "tpActive" );
        $("#myordersdiv").append(topping);
        clcik++;
        $("#myordersdiv").find("i.myorderhead22").text(clcik);
        $("#myordersdiv").show();
        //toppings.push(name);
   // }
});
```

But the selected element is not being reflected with that class ??
could anybody please help me ??

This is the complete css

```
<div class="Topping-details">
<img src="images/arrow-topping.png"/>
<section><i id="topping-close"></i>
<a href="#">Ketchup Extra - Rs. 25/-</a>
<a href="#" class="tpActive">Butter Extra - Rs. 25/-</a>
<a href="#">Cheeze Extra - Rs. 25/-</a>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: `$( this ).addClass( "tpActive" );`

Comment: on which "a" you want to add the class.. clicked one or  exist in topping variable

Comment: then use 'this' instead of "a"

Comment: I have tried with this itself , but still it isn't reflecting , i have added the complete css in my question , could you please let me know why itsn't relecfting ??

Comment: Why do you assign `topping` but never use it?

Comment: I have pasted my whole code in the question , please see that .

Comment: you are writing click event on ".secclass  a" but where is "secclass" in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function (e) {
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var topping='<div class="Topping-details"><section><a href="#">'+name+'</a></section></div>';
$( "a" ).each(function(){
    $(this).addClass( "tpActive" );
    });
});
```

let me know how it goes.

Comment: But how it is right... It will add class to all your "a" tags in html